# Error en la ejecución de mi app en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Soy nueva en el desarrollo de aplicaciones en Android Studio y me he topado con un problema que no he podido resolver.
Mi pantalla de inicio de sesión, al ingresar los datos correctamente, accede exitosamente y te redirige a la pantalla principal de la aplicación. El detalle es que pasan aproximadamente 5 segundos y el emulador deja de funcionar.
He revisado mi código pero no logro encontrar mi error. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme, por favor?

Comment: Buenas, Munchi, bienvenida al sitio. ¿Le has echado un ojo a [tour] y [ask]? Es un poco dificil ayudarte con la información que aportas. ¿Qué emulador estás usando? ¿Has comprobado si dicho emulador tiene un fichero de log en caso de error? Si lo tiene puede que te dé una pista de porque se produce ese comportamiento. Edita tu pregunta añadiendo esa información.